# Divergence of $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{3\sin x\cos x}{x^{2}-3x+2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I make sure that $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{3\sin x\cos x}{x^{2}-3x+2}dx$$ diverges?

I see that the integrand has a discontinuity at $x=1$ (a root of polynomial in the denominator). But may be it converges as an improper integral?

Comment: It diverges.  Near $x=1$ the function behaves like $\frac{k}{x-1}$ where $k$ is a non-zero constant.

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: Find the limit when we divide our function by $\frac{1}{x-1}$.

Comment: Finally, got it!

Comment: That's right. Now look at say the integral from say $\pi/6$ to $1$, The function is positive over this interval, and bigger than $\frac{c}{1-x}$ for some easily determined positive constant $c$. So by comparison the integral from $\pi/6$ to $1$ diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=1+\epsilon$, then
$$
\frac{3\sin x\cos x}{(x-2)(x-1)}=\frac{3\sin(1+\epsilon)\cos(1+\epsilon)}{(\epsilon-1)\epsilon}\approx-\frac{3\sin(1)\cos(1)}{\epsilon}
$$
when $\epsilon$ is very small.  But, integrating this in any neighborhood around $\epsilon=0$ (that is, $x=1$) will diverge -- just like integrating $\frac{1}{x}$ near $0$ does.

This constitutes more intuition than proof.  But, it leads to the right idea!

Pick a small interval $(1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)$ such that you can show that
your function is bounded away from $0$ by a function like $g(x)=\frac{C}{x}$ for $x\in(1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)$.  Then, by comparison, you'll be able to say that your original function diverges as well.